# How to show the trendline in half portion of an msline fusion chart?

Tags: html

Screen Shot

[image: Screen Shot]

```
window.renderScoreCardCharts = function(param) {
                //if( FusionCharts( "chartContainerFive" ) ) FusionCharts( "chartContainerFive" ).dispose();
                for(var i=0;i<=5;i++){
                var chartContainerFive = new FusionCharts(
                        {
                            /*"id": "scoreCardContainerBarId"+i,
                            "type" : "MSSPLine",
                            "type" : "MSLine",
                            "renderAt" : "scoreCardContainerBar"+i,
                            "width" : "100%",
                            "height" : "120px",
                            "dataFormat" : "json",*/

                        "id": "scoreCardContainerBarId"+i,
                        "renderAt" : "scoreCardContainerBar"+i,
                        "type": 'msline',
                        "width" : "100%",
                        "height" : "120px",
                        "dataFormat": 'json',



                        "dataSource" : {
                        "chart": {"caption": arr[i],
                            "captionFontSize" : "12",
                            "captionFontColor" : "#8a807c",
                            "captionFontBold" : "1",
                            "showLegend" : "0",
                            "bgcolor" : "FFFFFF",
                            "drawAnchors":"0",
                            "showalternatehgridcolor" : "1",
                            "showValues" : "0",
                            "canvasborderalpha" : "0",
                            //"legendposition" : "right",
                            "legendshadow" : "0",
                            "legendborderalpha" : "0",
                            "palettecolors" : "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e78",
                            "exportEnabled" : "0",
                            "exportFileName" : "QCDDMSESChange",
                            "showToolTipShadow" : "1",
                            "toolTipBorderRadius" : "6",
                            "canvasbgAlpha" : "5",
                            "showBorder" : "0",
                            "showColumnShadow" : "0",
                            "labelDisplay" : 'Normal',
                            /*  "slantLabels" : '0',*/
                            "canvasbgColor" : "#ff6418",
                            "legendNumColumns" : "13",
                            "legendItemFontSize":"8",
                            "showTrendlinesOnTop ":"0", 
                            "interactiveLegend":"1",
                            "theme":"fint",
                            "animation":"0",
                            "numberSuffix": " %",
                            "yAxisMinValue":"0.00",
                            "yAxisMaxValue":"100.00",
                            "minimizetendency": "1",
                            "numDivLines":"5",
                            "showShadow": "0",
                            "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                            "chartBottomMargin":"0",
                            "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                            /*"labelDisplay": "rotate",*/
                            "divlineThickness": "0",
                            "divLineDashed": "0",
                            "slantLabels": "0",
                            "divLineDashLen": "0",
                            "rotateValues" :"1",
                            "showToolTip" : "1",
                            "showAxisLines": "0"},
                        "styles": {
                            "definition": [
                              {
                                "name": "myToolTipFont",
                                "type": "font",
                                "size": "12"
                              }
                            ],
                            "application": [
                              {
                                "toobject": "ToolTip",
                                "styles": "myToolTipFont"
                              }
                            ]
                          },
                        "categories": [
                            {
                                "category": [
                                    {
                                        "label": "J",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "F",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "M",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "A",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "M",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "vLine": "true",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "J",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "J",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "A",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "S",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "O",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "N",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "D",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "label": "J",
                                        "fontSize" : "6"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ],
                        "dataset": [
                            {
                                "color": "#FF0000",
                                "seriesname": "Value ",
                                "data": [
                                    {
                                        "value": "44"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "48"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "54"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "64"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "55"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "51"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "60"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "70"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "78"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "80"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "81"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "82"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "value": "85"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }

                        ],
                       "trendlines": [
                                       {
                                           "line": [
                                               {
                                                   "startvalue": "80",
                                                    "endValue" : "85",
                                                    "dashed"   : "1"
                                               },
                                               {
                                                    "startvalue": "48",
                                                    "endValue" : "70",
                                                    "dashed"   : "1"
                                                }
                                         ]
                                       }
                                   ]
                        }

            });
    chartContainerFive.render();
            }

    }//window render chart
```

Answer (score 2):

The Trendlines feature cannot be used to fulfill your requirement of displaying two separate parts of trendline.

Alternatively, you could use the **Line Annotation** of FusionCharts to have a similar implementation as you require. For reference : http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/annotations/creating-annotations/creating-shape-annotations.html#line

To set the position of the line annotation, you could use the dynamic **positioning Macros**. For reference : http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/annotations/positioning-annotations-using-macros.html#positioning-annotations-with-respect-to-the-axes

Find a sample fiddle with similar implementation as you require : http://jsfiddle.net/Akash008/LE3Fa/154/

```
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
var chartContainerFive = new FusionCharts(
  {

    "id": "scoreCardContainerBarId",
    "renderAt" : "chart-container",
    "type": 'msline',
    "width" : "100%",
    "height" : "300",
    "dataFormat": 'json',



    "dataSource" : {
      "chart": {"caption": "Enter the Caption here",
                "captionFontSize" : "12",
                "captionFontColor" : "#8a807c",
                "captionFontBold" : "1",
                "showLegend" : "0",
                "bgcolor" : "FFFFFF",
                "drawAnchors":"0",
                "showalternatehgridcolor" : "1",
                "showValues" : "0",
                "canvasborderalpha" : "0",
                //"legendposition" : "right",
                "legendshadow" : "0",
                "legendborderalpha" : "0",
                "palettecolors" : "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e78",
                "exportEnabled" : "0",
                "exportFileName" : "QCDDMSESChange",
                "showToolTipShadow" : "1",
                "toolTipBorderRadius" : "6",
                "canvasbgAlpha" : "5",
                "showBorder" : "0",
                "showColumnShadow" : "0",
                "labelDisplay" : 'Normal',
                /*  "slantLabels" : '0',*/
                "canvasbgColor" : "#ff6418",
                "legendNumColumns" : "13",
                "legendItemFontSize":"8",
                "showTrendlinesOnTop ":"0", 
                "interactiveLegend":"1",
                "theme":"fint",
                "animation":"0",
                "numberSuffix": " %",
                "yAxisMinValue":"0.00",
                "yAxisMaxValue":"100.00",
                "minimizetendency": "1",
                "numDivLines":"5",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "chartBottomMargin":"0",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                /*"labelDisplay": "rotate",*/
                "divlineThickness": "0",
                "divLineDashed": "0",
                "slantLabels": "0",
                "divLineDashLen": "0",
                "rotateValues" :"1",
                "showToolTip" : "1",
                "showAxisLines": "0"},
      "styles": {
        "definition": [
          {
            "name": "myToolTipFont",
            "type": "font",
            "size": "12"
          }
        ],
        "application": [
          {
            "toobject": "ToolTip",
            "styles": "myToolTipFont"
          }
        ]
      },
      "categories": [
        {
          "category": [
            {
              "label": "J",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "F",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "M",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "A",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "M",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "vLine": "true",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "J",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "J",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "A",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "S",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "O",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "N",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "D",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            },
            {
              "label": "J",
              "fontSize" : "6"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "dataset": [
        {
          "color": "#FF0000",
          "seriesname": "Value ",
          "data": [
            {
              "value": "44"
            },
            {
              "value": "48"
            },
            {
              "value": "54"
            },
            {
              "value": "64"
            },
            {
              "value": "55"
            },
            {
              "value": "51"
            },
            {
              "value": "60"
            },
            {
              "value": "70"
            },
            {
              "value": "78"
            },
            {
              "value": "80"
            },
            {
              "value": "81"
            },
            {
              "value": "82"
            },
            {
              "value": "85"
            }
          ]
        }

      ],
      /*"trendlines": [
        {
          "line": [
            {
              "startvalue": "80",
              "endValue" : "85",
              "dashed"   : "1"
            },
            {
              "startvalue": "48",
              "endValue" : "70",
              "dashed"   : "1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],*/
      "annotations": {
        "showBelow" : "0",
        "width": "500",
        "height": "100",
        "autoScale": "1",
        "groups": [
          {
            "id": "user-images",
            "items": [
              {
                  "id": "line-part-1",
                  "type": "line",

                  "color": "#00FF00",
                  "x": "$xaxis.label.0.x",
                  "y": "$yaxis.label.2.y",

                  "toX": "$xaxis.label.4.x+22",
                  "toY": "$yaxis.label.2.y"
              },
              {
                  "id": "line-part-2",
                  "type": "line",

                  "color": "##0000FF",
                  "x": "$xaxis.label.4.x+22",
                  "y": "$yaxis.label.3.y",

                  "toX": "$xaxis.label.12.x+4",
                  "toY": "$yaxis.label.3.y"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
});
chartContainerFive.render();
});
```